# Listview custom Adapter On click

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom adapter where each row have 2 layouts each having TextView's. Now how can I get the text of the row which has been clicked by the user.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: set click listener to the layouts individually.

Comment: i have 2layout in 1row so i can have n number of rows

Comment: i tired onitem click but in this i will get position of row

Comment: Yes pass that position in the array which you are inflating in the list item. like I have described in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the click and then get the value/text for that position from the text array.

e.g your array name is 
`String[] titles = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};`

So when the user clicks on the item in the listview you will get its position based on the value from onItemClickListener. So you can take that value(int) and do like this.

`String textClicked = titles[position];` // It will return the text stored at that position.

If you still got doubts then comment below and I will help you with the same.

OR

In the Custom Adapter you can do like this :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] titles = same as mentioned above.. Let it be the String which you will get as the title of the each row of ListView

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
Log.d("title", titles[position]); // It will log the text of that clicked position. now you can use it in Toast, TextView etc...
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: i have 2layout in 1row so i can have n number of rows

Comment: Yes, right but when you implement OnItemClickListener then you have to override the onClick method... and there you will get the position of the clicked item. You can pass that position in your String array of the data you are inflating in the ListView. that you give you the text there... It dosnt matter how many rows or components you are having in the ListView. you just have to pass in the right String array name

Comment: Added 1 more example for your understanding. This is the last comment from my end as you have not provided any code and not responding to any of the help you have been provided with.